# LAPACKE or MAGMA GPU - inversion of matrix with Cholesky factorization - functions magma_dpotrf_gpu and magma_dpotri_gpu

Tags: gpu, lapack, matrix-inverse, lapacke, magma

I have a first version of a function that inverses a matrix of size `m` and using
`magma_dgetrf_gpu` and `magma_dgetri_gpu`like this :

```
  // Inversion
  magma_dgetrf_gpu( m, m, d_a, m, piv, &info);
  magma_dgetri_gpu( m, d_a, m, piv, dwork, ldwork, &info);
```

Now, I would like to also inverse but using the Cholesky decomposition. The function looks like the first version one,except the functions used which are :

```
  // Inversion
  magma_dpotrf_gpu( MagmaLower, m, d_a, m, &info);
  magma_dpotri_gpu( MagmaLower, m, d_a, m, &info);
```

Here is the entire function that inverses :

```
// ROUTINE MAGMA TO INVERSE WITH CHOLESKY
void matrix_inverse_magma(vector<vector<double>> const &F_matrix, vector<vector<double>> &F_output) {

  // Index for loop and arrays
  int i, j, ip, idx;

  // Start magma part
  magma_int_t m = F_matrix.size();
  if (m) {
  magma_init (); // initialize Magma
  magma_queue_t queue=NULL;
  magma_int_t dev=0;
  magma_queue_create(dev ,&queue );
  double gpu_time , *dwork; // dwork - workspace
  magma_int_t ldwork; // size of dwork
  magma_int_t *piv, info; // piv - array of indices of inter -
  // changed rows; a - mxm matrix
  magma_int_t mm=m*m; // size of a, r, c
  double *a; // a- mxm matrix on the host
  double *d_a; // d_a - mxm matrix a on the device
 
  magma_int_t err;
  ldwork = m * magma_get_dgetri_nb( m ); // optimal block size
  // allocate matrices
  err = magma_dmalloc_cpu( &a , mm ); // host memory for a

  // Convert matrix to *a double pointer
  for (i = 0; i<m; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<m; j++){
      idx = i*m + j;
      a[idx] = F_matrix[i][j];
    }
  }
  err = magma_dmalloc( &d_a , mm ); // device memory for a
  err = magma_dmalloc( &dwork , ldwork );// dev. mem. for ldwork
  piv=( magma_int_t *) malloc(m*sizeof(magma_int_t ));// host mem.

  magma_dsetmatrix( m, m, a, m, d_a, m, queue); // copy a -> d_a

  // Inversion
  magma_dpotrf_gpu( MagmaLower, m, d_a, m, &info);
  magma_dpotri_gpu( MagmaLower, m, d_a, m, &info);

  magma_dgetmatrix( m, m, d_a , m, a, m, queue); // copy d_a ->a

  // Save Final matrix
  for (i = 0; i<m; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<m; j++){
      idx = i*m + j;
      F_output[i][j] = a[idx];
    }
  }

  free(a); // free host memory
  free(piv); // free host memory
  magma_free(d_a); // free device memory
  magma_queue_destroy(queue); // destroy queue
  magma_finalize (); 
  // End magma part
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, after checking the output data, I have a wrong inversion with my implementation.

I have doubts about the using at this line :

```
  ldwork = m * magma_get_dgetri_nb( m ); // optimal block size
```

Could anyone see at first sight where the error comes from in my using of `dpotrf` and `dpotri` functions (actually `magma_dpotrf_gpu` and `magma_dpotri_gpu`) ?

**EDIT 1:**

following the advice of Damir Tenishev, I put an example of a function that inverses a matrix using LAPACKE :

```
// LAPACK version
void matrix_inverse_lapack(vector<vector<double>> const &F_matrix, vector<vector<double>> &F_output) {

  // Index for loop and arrays
  int i, j, ip, idx;

  // Size of F_matrix
  int N = F_matrix.size();

  int *IPIV = new int[N];

  // Statement of main array to inverse
  double *arr = new double[N*N];

  // Output Diagonal block
  double *diag = new double[N];

  for (i = 0; i<N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<N; j++){
      idx = i*N + j;
      arr[idx] = F_matrix[i][j];
    }
  }

  // LAPACKE routines
  int info1 = LAPACKE_dgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, N, arr, N, IPIV);
  int info2 = LAPACKE_dgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, N, arr, N, IPIV);

  for (i = 0; i<N; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<N; j++){
      idx = i*N + j;
      F_output[i][j] = arr[idx];
    }
  }

  delete[] IPIV;
  delete[] arr;
}
```

As you can see, this is a classical version of matrix inversion, which uses `LAPACKE_dgetrf` and `LAPACKE_dgetri`

**EDIT 2:** The `MAGMA` version is :

```
// MAGMA version
void matrix_inverse_magma(vector<vector<double>> const &F_matrix, vector<vector<double>> &F_output) {

  // Index for loop and arrays
  int i, j, ip, idx;

  // Start magma part
  magma_int_t m = F_matrix.size();

  if (m) {
  magma_init (); // initialize Magma
  magma_queue_t queue=NULL;
  magma_int_t dev=0;
  magma_queue_create(dev ,&queue );
  double gpu_time , *dwork; // dwork - workspace
  magma_int_t ldwork; // size of dwork
  magma_int_t *piv, info; // piv - array of indices of inter -

  // changed rows; a - mxm matrix
  magma_int_t mm=m*m; // size of a, r, c
  double *a; // a- mxm matrix on the host
  double *d_a; // d_a - mxm matrix a on the device
 
  magma_int_t ione = 1;
  magma_int_t ISEED [4] = { 0,0,0,1 }; // seed
  magma_int_t err;
  const double alpha = 1.0; // alpha =1
  const double beta = 0.0; // beta=0
  ldwork = m * magma_get_dgetri_nb( m ); // optimal block size
  // allocate matrices
  err = magma_dmalloc_cpu( &a , mm ); // host memory for a

  for (i = 0; i<m; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<m; j++){
      idx = i*m + j;
      a[idx] = F_matrix[i][j]
    }
  }
  err = magma_dmalloc( &d_a , mm ); // device memory for a
  err = magma_dmalloc( &dwork , ldwork );// dev. mem. for ldwork
  piv=( magma_int_t *) malloc(m*sizeof(magma_int_t ));// host mem.

  magma_dsetmatrix( m, m, a, m, d_a, m, queue); // copy a -> d_a

  // find the inverse matrix: d_a*X=I using the LU factorization
  // with partial pivoting and row interchanges computed by
  // magma_dgetrf_gpu; row i is interchanged with row piv(i);
  // d_a -mxm matrix; d_a is overwritten by the inverse

  magma_dgetrf_gpu( m, m, d_a, m, piv, &info);
  magma_dgetri_gpu(m, d_a, m, piv, dwork, ldwork, &info);

  magma_dgetmatrix( m, m, d_a , m, a, m, queue); // copy d_a ->a

  for (i = 0; i<m; i++){
    for (j = 0; j<m; j++){
      idx = i*m + j;
      F_output[i][j] = a[idx];
    }
  }

  free(a); // free host memory
  free(piv); // free host memory
  magma_free(d_a); // free device memory
  magma_queue_destroy(queue); // destroy queue
  magma_finalize (); 
  // End magma part
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have used `magma_dgetrf_gpu` and `magma_dgetri_gpu` functions.

Now, I would like to do the same, either with `LAPACKE` or `MAGMA+LAPACK`, using `dpotrf` and `dpotri` functions. I recall that the matrixes that I inverse are symmetric.

**EDIT 3:** my attempts come from [this documentation link](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/Misc/mygpu.pdf)

Especially, see section 4.4.21 `magma dpotri - invert a positive definite matrix in double precision, CPU interface` on page 325.

Comment: It is necessary to see how you provide the initial data to the function. For example, dpotrf and dpotri require upper or lower triangle to be stored and I am not sure you prepare the data accordingly; the code after the "// Convert matrix to *a double pointer" looks suspiciously here: this is not a triangle matrix but full one.
It would help if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that people can help.

Comment: @DamirTenishev . Thanks, I have put a LAPACK example and a MAGMA example. Regards

Comment: It would help if you share somewhere (github, etc.) source code of some minimal **runnable** example. Something with main function, calls, expected values, etc. So that people can download, run and see the real issue as you see it.

Comment: @DamirTenishev . Hi ! I provided the documentation link : https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/Misc/mygpu.pdf , example on page 325 of PDF

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410831/681865